# Nested Loops through one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In my music review app the Pins model has attributes of Pin.artist and Pin.album. I'm trying to list each artist reviewed on the site and which albums of theirs have been reviewed. Below is what I have so far, but I want to do it without repeating the artist name.

Controller:

```
@pin_albums = Pin.group(:album).order('artist')
```

View:

```
<% @pin_albums.each do |pin| %>
  <%= pin.artist %> | 
  <%= link_to pin.album, copy_pin_path(pin) %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

This lists them like this:

```
The Beatles | Let It Be
The Beatles | Abbey Road
Bob Dylan | Blood On The Tracks
Bob Dylan | Highway 61 Revisited
```

I want to list them like so:

```
The Beatles | Let It Be
            | Abbey Road
Bob Dylan | Blood On The Tracks
          | Highway 61 Revisited
```

I need to do something to the effect of:

```
<% @pin_albums.each do |pin| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= pin.artist %></li> 
      <ul>
      <% pin.artist.each do |pin_album| %> 
        <li><%= link_to pin_album.album, pin_album %></li>
      <% end %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

I know that the above nested tables won't work, but that's the gist of what I'm trying to figure out.

The above nested code gives me an "Undefined method 'each'" on the pin.artist.each line.

Comment: Why doesn't what you posted work? Do you get an error? You aren't asking a question.

Comment: Sorry, my question was clear in my head, but not so clear in my text. I added the error above. I didn't expect my nested table to work, but that's the best way to show where my thinking is at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the pin.artist in a local variable and only print it when it changes.

```
<% last_artist = nil %>
    <% @pin_albums.each do |pin| %>
      <%= last_artist  != pin.artist ? (last_artist = pin.artist) : '' %> | 
      <%= link_to pin.album, copy_pin_path(pin) %>
      <br/>
    <% end %>
```

EDIT
Moved scope of local variable

Comment: This outputs the same thing as my original code, with every artist listed next to the album title. In this code, does the app know what last_artist means in terms of this .each do loop?

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't work.  last_artist is compared to pin.artist... if it's not equal last_artist is set to equal pin.artist and it's output.

If it is equal, then an empty string is output.

Comment: The `last_artist ||= nil` is just to define it on the first time through.

Comment: I see, so you're setting the local variable last_artist the first time, then it increments each time through? What If I @pin_albums.each.with_index?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Instead of scope variable `pin` you have `pin, index` but you still have access to `pin.album`

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. As I read the code it declares a local variable last_artist and sets it equal to last_artist or nil, then says that if it doesn't equal pin.artist print ' ', then set last_artist to pin.artist. Is that correct? If so it sounds like it should work. (I'm not very familiar with using local variables in a Rails app)

Comment: No, if it doesn't equal `pin.artist` it sets `last_artist = pin.artist` and prints THAT.  It only prints blank `''` if last_artist already equals pin.artist

Comment: I figured out a solution which I posted. Someone suggested to me that the scope of teh variables was the issue in your suggestion. Here is his comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubyonrails-talk/jWcKXQyXM10/8IrzIPzNpsYJ

Comment: Do you want to revise your answer and I'll test it and upvote it if it works? It could help someone else. Thanks a lot. You've been a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing to accomplish this. (I put it into a table for styling purposes)

```
<% last_artist ||= nil %>
  <table id="artist">
    <tr>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Album</th>
   </tr>
<% @pin_albums.each do |pin| %>  
  <% if last_artist != pin.artist %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= pin.artist %></td>
      <td><%= link_to image_tag(pin.image), pin %></td>
      <td><%= link_to pin.album, copy_pin_path(pin) %></td>
    </tr>  
  <% else %>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><%= link_to image_tag(pin.image), pin %></td>
      <td><%= link_to pin.album, copy_pin_path(pin) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>     
  <% last_artist = pin.artist %>     
<% end %>
```

I set the local variable last_artist ||= nil to start, based on Steve's suggestion above, and then set last_artist = pin.artist at the end of each loop.